# X11 forwarding via SSH and su

Tags: ssh, x11, su

For me, it is weird that while using ssh connection with X11 forwarding, a user and root are able to see `xclock`, but another user is not able to see that. Why?

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ xclock
^C
mahmood@cluster:~$ su
Password:
root@cluster:mahmood# xclock
^C
root@cluster:mahmood# su - hmousavi
hmousavi@cluster:~$ xclock
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
hmousavi@cluster:~$
```

P.S: `^C` means that I was able to see the `xclock` window, so I pressed `^C` to return to the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried `su --preserve-environment - hmousavi` to preserve the enviroment variable `DISPLAY`?

Comment: Doesn't work either `MobaXterm X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
\\ Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0`

Comment: Try `su -` instead of `su`.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to an X11 display requires two pieces of information: the display name (normally passed in the `DISPLAY` environment variable) and the *cookie*, which is a password for the display that every application must show when connecting. Typically the cookie is stored in `~/.Xauthority`, but it can be stored in a different file indicated by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable.

It appears that the value of `DISPLAY` set by SSH was preserved by the two calls to `su`. However the cookie is in `~mahmood/.Xauthority`; when you run a program as hmousavi, the program looks for a cookie in `~hmousavi/.Xauthority` and finds a different value.

In principle you could run `XAUTHORITY=~mahmood/.Xauthority xclock`, but hmousavi presumably doesn't have the permission to read that file — the `.Xauthority` file should not be readable to other users. You can use the `xauth` command twice, once as mahmood to extract the cookie value (`xauth list localhost:10.0`) and once as hmousavi to import that value (`xauth merge`), but that's cumbersome. The easiest way to make X11 applications work is to use SSH all the way, because SSH sets up X11 forwarding automatically:

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ ssh -X hmousavi@localhost
hmousavi@cluster:~$ xclock
```

Add mahmood's SSH public key to hmousavi's `.ssh/authorized_keys` to allow this.

Comment: What is the command for the last line? Just want to be sure that I am doing exactly what you said

Comment: @mahmood From mahmood's account, run `ssh-copy-id hmousavi@localhost`. Or, if you're connecting to mahmood@cluster over SSH, maybe you could connect directly to the hmousavi account instead.

Comment: It says `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found`

Comment: @mahmood That means the account doesn't have a key. You can create one, or use the one from your client machine, or use hmousavi's password if that's permitted by the SSH server configuration.

Comment: Can you edit the answer for supplying those information? I know the command `ssh-keygen` but since the cluster is based on Rocks, I want to be sure that modifying the ssh keys has no side effect on the nodes (the passwordless ssh to nodes)

Comment: Other possiblity with `XAUTHORITY`: As user `mahmood` or  `root` run: `xhost +SI:localuser:hmousavi`

Comment: @mviereck I've meant 'without XAUTHORITY', not 'with XAUTHORITY'.